# Sending Email via Powershell Renders a Connection Error 10060

Tags: powershell, email, smtp

I'm testing a new Powershell script which will enventually be a scheduled task once I get it to work.  I am trying to send the message via Yahoo mail which uses port 587 and TSL.  The smtp server is smtp.mail.yahoo.com and I can successfully telnet the address.  When I try to run the code, it eventually hangs up with the following message:

Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server
response was: Cannot connect to SMTP server 206.190.49.106 (206.190.49.106:587), connect error 10060"
At C:\users\rob\dropbox\PowershellSendEmail.ps1:23 char:1

- $smtp.Send($message)
- CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException

There is no firewall or anti-virus program in the way.  Any ideas on what is causing this?  The code is attached.

```
        $toaddress = "blah@blah.com"
        $Subject = "Testing 4pm Message"
        $body = "this is a test."
        $attachment = "C:\users\text.txt"
        $smtpserver = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
        $smtpuser = "blah@blah.com"
        $smtpPassword = "test1" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
        $smtpport = 587

        $message = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        $message.From = $fromaddress
        $message.To.Add($toaddress)
        $message.IsBodyHtml = $False
        $message.Subject = $Subject
        $attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment)
        $message.Attachments.Add($attach)
        $message.body = $body
        $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver, $smtpport)
        [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
        $smtp.Credentials = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist 
            $smtpuser,$smtpPassword
        $smtp.Timeout = 400000
        $smtp.Send($message)
```

Comment: Maybe `$smtp.EnableSsl = $true` may help

Comment: Good idea Daniel . . . I added the line, but unfortunately it made no difference.

Comment: I wanted to see if the problem was specific to the ISP.  I initiated the same process with a Gmail account and received the same error.  Before doing so, I made sure to unblock outside apps.  So somewhere, somehow, the problem is with the code.

Comment: Should I contact the ISP directly?  I am still stumped.